# Программа сама закрывает кавычки, скобки т.д. Как от этого избавиться?

Tags: phpstorm

Допустим, открываю двойные кавычки, а шторм уже ставит рядом закрывающую кавычку. Как-то непривычно мне так) это можно как-нить исправить?

Comment: Settings - Editor - Smart Keys - Insert pair quotes

но лучше оставьте.

Comment: я привык всегда открыкать и закрыть кавычки и все остальное )

Comment: тогда лучше заюзать блокнот)

Comment: Ну это действительно иногда мешает, особенно после перехода из среды, где такая возможность отсутствует(или отключена по умолчанию)

Comment: @MDJHD, таким образом можно всю жизнь отказываться от удобств в силу привычки. Это ммм не очень хоро для профессионального опыта.

Comment: @Etki, ну я имел ввиду, что иногда эта вторая ковычка и не нужна вовсе, а тут софтина ее уже тебе подсунула, а ты забываешь про это и потом ищешь, где-же эта коварная ошибочка закралась в код(скрипт) :)